# FizzBuzz problem is not working: java implementation

Tags: java

I am trying to write a Fizzbuzz problem that returns a list of strings. Currently this program is returning FIzzBuzz when I give input as 1. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
class Solution {
    public List<String> fizzBuzz(int n) {
        List<String> ans = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0)){
              ans.add("FizzBuzz");  
            }
            else if(i%3==0){
                ans.add("Fizz");
            }
            else if(i%5==0){
                ans.add("Buzz");
            }
            else{
                ans.add(Integer.toString(i));
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

sample input : 1
expected output: "1"
current output: "FizzBuzz"

Comment: Hint: When `i` is zero, `(i%3==0)&&(i%5==0)` is `true`.

Comment: Looks like a good time to learn about debugger.

Comment: The for loop works on every number from 0 up to but not including 1. Try making i<n into i<=n. And if you really don't like starting the game at 0, start with for int i = 1. See http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/nodebugger.html for why you may want to get in the habit of tracing through things by hand without a debugger.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, it really helped

Answer (score 1):

You're starting at 0, therefor 0 % 3 (or 5) will give you an output of fizz (or buzz). Change i to start at 1